# помогите решить задачу по Java

Tags: java

Напишите функцию (и напишите ее код в ответе), которая принимает на вход n слов и возвращает предложение, в котором эти слова отсортированы по количеству гласных.

Comment: Покажите ваш вариант кода, мы поправим

Answer (score 1):

дак сделай динамический массив ArrayList<>положи туда слова, далее через Stream API сделай сортировку почему стрим, меньше кода